# How do I flatten a single level of directories in a terminal command?

Tags: bash, unix

I've found lots of scripts which will recursively flatten all the contents of the subfolders and the subfolders of those subfolders of a directory. But I just want to flatten one level and keep the subfolders intact. How would I go about doing that with maybe a bash script?

Comment: please define what you think "flattening" means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mv */* .
```

If you don't care about hidden directories, it's as simple as that.

Comment: Add the `.[!.]*` and `..?*` globs to that and you get everything.

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir -p dir0/dir1/dirA/dirX
mkdir -p dir0/dir2/dirB/dirY
mkdir -p dir0/dir3/dirC/dirZ
```

Let's see how it is now:

```
tree dir0
```

Returns:

```
dir0/
├── dir1
│   └── dirA
│       └── dirX
├── dir2
│   └── dirB
│       └── dirY
└── dir3
    └── dirC
        └── dirZ
```

Now let's run

```
find dir0 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec mv -i '{}' dir0 ';'
```

Let's look how dir0 is now:

```
tree dir0
```

Result:

```
dir0
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── dir3
├── dirA
│   └── dirX
├── dirB
│   └── dirY
└── dirC
    └── dirZ
```

Ps: You could also run something like this:

```
 mv dir0/*/* dir0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
array=($(ls))
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        cd $i
        ls
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

gets you the ls output of every first level subdir plus everything from the top level.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `array=(*)` would be better.